# Problems with index

Tags: table-of-contents

I have various problem with `\tableofcontents`, `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables`.

In particular, if I write:

```
\tableofcontents 
\listoffigures
\listoftables
```

I have these errors:

for line 87 (...tazione dei task avanzati e risultati is the title of chapter 7):

```
 ! Missing \endcsname inserted.<to be read again>\protect ...tazione dei task avanzati e risultati}{91}
 ! Extra \endcsname.\thepage ...me @{\color {azzurro}Roman}\endcsname\c@page ...tazione dei task avanzati e risultati}{91}
 ! Missing number, treated as zero.<to be read again>\hss ...tazione dei task avanzati e risultati}{91}
 ! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.\@outputpage ...or \hb@xt@ \textwidth {\@thehead }\color@endbox }\dp \@tempb... ...tazione dei task avanzati e risultati}{91}
```

for line 82:

```
 ! Missing \endcsname inserted.<to be read again>\protect \listoffigures
\documentclass[envcountsame,envcountchap]{svmono}
 ! Extra \endcsname.\thepage ...me @{\color {azzurro}Roman}\endcsname\c@page \listoffigures
 ! Missing number, treated as zero.<to be read again>} \listoffigures
 ! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.\@outputpage ...or \hb@xt@ \textwidth {\@thehead }\color@endbox }\dp \@tempb... \listoffigures
```

for line 75 ( Creazione del database WASM is the caption of a figure):

```
 ! Missing \endcsname inserted.<to be read again>\protect ...respaces Creazione del database WASM}}{94}
 ! Extra \endcsname.\thepage ...me @{\color {azzurro}Roman}\endcsname\c@page ...respaces Creazione del database WASM}}{94}
 ! Missing number, treated as zero.<to be read again>\hss ...respaces Creazione del database WASM}}{94}
 ! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.\@outputpage ...or \hb@xt@ \textwidth {\@thehead }\color@endbox }\dp \@tempb... ...respaces Creazione del database WASM}}{94}
```

for line 83:

```
 ! Missing \endcsname inserted.<to be read again>\protect \listoftables
 ! Extra \endcsname.\thepage ...me @{\color {azzurro}Roman}\endcsname\c@page \listoftables
 ! Missing number, treated as zero.<to be read again>} \listoftables
 ! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.\@outputpage ...or \hb@xt@ \textwidth {\@thehead }\color@endbox }\dp \@tempb... \listoftables
```

and then, at line 1:

```
 Overfull \hbox (28.90535pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
```

This is the file:

```
 \documentclass[envcountsame,envcountchap]{svmono}
 %\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{makeidx}                % allows index generation
\usepackage{graphicx}               % standard LaTeX graphics tool
\usepackage{xtab}                   % when including figure files
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{latexsym}
 \usepackage{psfig}                  % used for the two-column index
 \usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}       % places footnotes at page bottom
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{my_listings}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
 \usepackage{titlesec}
  \usepackage{csquotes}
   \usepackage{python}
  \usepackage{verbatim}
  \usepackage{eurosym}
  \usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
 \usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
%\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
%\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\makeatletter
\titleformat{\section}[display]%
  {\Large\bfseries\boldmath}{\color{azzurro}{\thesection}}{-1.1em}{\hspace{2em}\color{azzurro}}[{\titlerule[0pt]}]
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\titleformat{\subsection}[display]%
  {\large\bfseries\boldmath}{\color{gold}{\thesubsection}}{-1em}{\hspace{3em}\color{gold}}[{\titlerule[0pt]}]
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[display]%
  {\normalsize\bfseries\boldmath}{\color{gold}{\thesubsubsection}}{-1em}{\color{gold}}[{\titlerule[0pt]}]
\makeatother

\definecolor{gold}{rgb}{0.64,0.54,0.29}
\definecolor{azzurro}{rgb}{0,0.29,0.57}

\def\lstlistlistingname{\textbf{Elenco dei listati}}
\addto\captionsitalian{\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\textbf{Indice}}}
\addto\captionsitalian{\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\textbf{Elenco delle figure}}}


\makeatletter
\let\old@rule\@rule
\def\@rule[#1]#2#3{\textcolor{gold}{\old@rule[#1]{#2}{#3}}}
\makeatother

\setlength{\textwidth}{12.7cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{20.0cm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{3.50cm}
\setlength {\evensidemargin}{-0.3cm}
\setlength {\topmargin}{-1cm}


\makeindex

\author{}

\date{13 marzo 2018}

\begin{document}
%line75

\pagenumbering{{\color{azzurro}Roman}}
%\include{frontespizio/frontespizio}
%\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage
%\include{dedica/dedica}
\tableofcontents 
\listoffigures  %line82
\listoftables   %line83

\pagenumbering{arabic} \setcounter{page}{1}

%\include{Introduzione/introduzione}  %line87
\include{01-IlCrowdsourcing/capitolo-01}
\include{02-LaSentimentAnalysis/capitolo-02}
\include{03-ProgettazioneDeiTaskDiBase/capitolo-03}
\include{04-ImplementazioneDeiTaskDiBaseERisultati/capitolo-04}
\include{05-ProgettazioneDeiTaskAvanzati/capitolo-05}
\include{06-ImplementazioneDeiTaskAvanzatiERisultati/capitolo-06}
\include{07-ConfrontoConApprocciCorrelati/capitolo-07}
\include{08-DiscussioneInMeritoAll'attivitàSvolta/capitolo-08}

\nocite{*}
%\bibliography{Bibliografia/biblio}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
%\include{Ringraziamenti/ringraziamenti}
\end{document}
```

But if I compile only `\listoftables`, it works! The problem is on `\tableofcontents` or `\listoffigures`!

Moreover, if I compile without these indexes, there are no errors!

I tried to compile with pdflatex and latex too.

Thank you for answers.

Edit:
For example, this is a piece of book.lof:

```
\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {6.6}{\ignorespaces Diagramma di sequenza per il subtask ``Analisi tramite Watson Analytics For Social Media''}}{88}
\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {6.7}{\ignorespaces Diagramma di sequenza per il subtask ``Analisi tramite Watson Analytics''}}{89}
\addvspace {10\p@ }
\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {7.1}{\ignorespaces Mappa dei luoghi fotografati di Guanajuato}}{92}
\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {7.2}{\ignorespaces Mappa della soddisfazione nei quartieri di Londra}}{95}
```

Really, 7.1 and 7.2 are 8.1 and 8.2!! All the figures of the 7th doesn't exist. And it's the same for book.toc.
\listoftables works beacause in chapter 7 there aren't tables!

All the chapters have this structure (the files included):

```
\chapter{title of chapter}
\label{capitolo-07}

\emph{explains what the chapter is about}

\section{title of section}
La gestione del database comprende una serie di operazioni
utili per la creazione e la modifica dello stesso.

\subsection{title of subsection}
etc etc etc
```

Maybe, there is a difference: in chapter 7 I used labels like this

```
Figure \ref{fig:g1}
```

where there are letter and number; in the others I used only letters in the labels.

EDIT: chapter 7 is not the problem. If I compile only 7, it works.
But if I compile 6 and 7, not works.
1 and 2 not works, 1 and 3 works, 1 and 4 no, 1 and 6 yes, 6 and 7 no, 7 and 8 yes, and so on. It depends by the chapters I choose to compile. I don't understand what is the problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your fragment of code is not useful since everything that appears in the ToC etc. is inside of files not shown here. Also there is no `\documentclass`. As it stands there is no indication whether you really have a problem with the Index -- which is something different than the ToC etc.

Comment: What happens if you make a copy of the file, then delete things until you have the smallest possible file which still has those errors? This will narrow down the problem.

Comment: I also doubt that you really require `latexsym` and `psfig` packages

Comment: Sorry! I forgot the documentclass. I edit the question. I added latexsym and psfig packages but nothing has changed!

Comment: @Jane: Not adding them, removing them. And your example is still incomplete. There are 8 `\include` statements for files we don't have.

Comment: It's the same thing. I opened the book.toc and the book.lof files, and it's vary strange, because chapter 6 is ok, then chapter 7 doesn't exist, and chapter 8 is indicated like 7. But all chapters have the same structure!

Comment: Did you try to delete all auxiliary files and compile twice?

Comment: Yes. Doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If I delete `\pagenumbering{{\color{azzurro}Roman}}` everything works!

Comment: `\pagenumbering{{\color{azzuro}Roman}}`  must fail, in my point of view.

Comment: Well, `\pagenumbering` takes a style name like `Roman` as an argument, not any typesetting code like `\color`. This will not color the page numbers! As the argument is taken as text and `\color` does not expand to text only an error is caused.